# C# equivalent for Python's pdb.set_trace()

Tags: c#, debugging

Does c# have an interactive debugger (or a library to do so), similar to the one that Python's `pdb` module offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Debugger.Launch()`

You can find documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is useful information: `If a debugger is already attached, nothing happens.`

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio is IDE where you can debug .

Comment: See my comment to @Christos

Comment: Well, he deleted his answer, so let me comment here again. I'm building a framework that runs user-written code. Now, I'm trying to make the debugger for that framework so I can connect it to IDEs like vs-code. Can't figure out how I can make the debugger for the user-written code.

Comment: @YotamSalmon thanks I misunderstood the question . I can delete my answer if you want.

Comment: Nah, no need. That way I can point other misunderstood answers to my comment here ;)